# Where to store .NET application settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

I have a .NET application that needs to reference a global application variable, a number, which is used by the application to allow/disallow users to enter events prior to a date.  Currently I have

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="beginDateRangeDays" value="60" />
    <add key="endDateRangeDays" value="30" />
</appSettings>
```

in my Web.config.  I want the admin users to be able to modify those values periodically via an admin web page.  If I allow this, every time they make a change, my app pool will restart.

Where would you recommend storing this?  In an external config file? But will that also cause an app pool restart?  Should I use a config table in the application's database?

Comment: I think a config table makes sense here, especially since you want to allow web access.

Comment: If you're worried about forcing an app pool restart, I'd store it in a table in a database.

Comment: This feels a bit broad. To answer your question: You can't store it anywhere where it'll be picked up by the `web.config`. What sort of application is it? ASP.NET? ASP.NET MVC? It sounds like something that could just be stored in whatever persistence mechanism you're already using for your project.  Your Web config should be for variables that don't change for the life of the app; so this would be a poor place to put global variables.

Comment: That sounds more like User's settings than Global application settings. 

So, you should make some room in the database per-user. And probably set a default value initialization in Global.asax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the admin users to be able to modify those values periodically via an admin web page

Database, definitely.  The config file is a convenient place to store non-static values, but not always the best place.  Step back for a moment and consider two "buckets" of such values:

1. Logical configurations which users can change within any given instance of the application.
2. Infrastructure configurations which *define* any given instance of the application and how it relates to the surrounding environment.

The former is best kept in the application's database, the latter in the config file.  The former might contain values like:

- Business holidays observed this year
- Values used in calculating business data
- Defaults for user forms

While the latter might contain values like:

- Database connection strings
- URLs for external web services
- Credentials for service accounts

Let the users change things that they can change without physically breaking the application, and track those changes in the database.  Keep the infrastructure details in the config file, since a change to those details would *very likely* require an app pool restart anyway.

Comment: All very valid points.  In many of our tables we track the date and userstamp of the last person to modify or add the value.  I might add that to my new config table as well.  I agree, the web.config is an easy place, easily edited via text editor, but those values should not be constantly changing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to setup application settings, such that they are editable in IIS.  See this TechNet article:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753062(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I don't think I want my non-technical staff making changes via IIS.

Comment: Didnt know they were non-tech.  Must've misread, "I want the admin users to be able to modify those values" -- You should put it in a database

Answer (score 0):

If you store it in the database then you have control over who accesses it and when.  Then you need not worry about making the app pool restart.